# Probability, mathematical symbol

Tags: notation

Good day,

Would like to ask about the meaning of ^ in P(S^B) as shown in the image below. Thanks for your help!!

Regards,
Math noob

[image: ques]

Comment: It usually means 'and'.

Comment: Intersection of two sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\wedge$ symbol is the *and* operator, so on the first line, $P(S \wedge B)=P(S)P(B)$ says "The probability of both $S$ and $B$ equals the probability of $S$ times the probability of $B$".

Comment: how do you calculate that? does that mean joint distribution P(S,B)?

Comment: [This wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)) should answer that for you, at least for the first line, regarding statistical independence. Note that they use the intersection symbol $\cap$ in the wiki, but there is a correlation between the symbols $\wedge$ and $\cap$. You will see that correlation I am sure. I can not improve on this wiki, and yes that is joint probability.